# How do retail sites populate pages with individual product information?

Tags: php, html

This is a silly question and I will get some backlash for it, but I don't know how to ask the question in search bars, so I can't find the answer.

I'm trying to figure out how sites like ebay, pccasegear etc populate their product page with information about each specific item.

I know they obviously wouldn't have a html page for each product, which is ridiculous. So I assume they would have to have a single product page which was populated from a database by php or something like this.

My question is, how is this done? and how could I go about coding this without using php or using a database?

I ask this because I am required to code a website for my course, and it asks to have 12+ dummy products, and I do not want to create a html page for each product.

Comment: @JohnConde I am sufficiently aware of how databases work, because I have designed quite a few in my course. I was mainly asking how it comes into play in the html side and how I could replicate this on a minor scale.

Comment: Wait, so do you want to use PHP or not? You don't necessarily need a database for this, but you'll need some sort of dynamic language if you don't want an html file for each page. You could do this, for example, with a very simple Ember.js app. One single file of HTML that contains some JS, too.

Comment: I would like to avoid all other languages other than html and css. My assignment states that I am not required to use any other language, so I believe it is an error when it asks us to code 12 viewable products from one page separately.

Comment: Not being required and not being allowed are two different things... Why do you want to avoid other languages?

Comment: I'm doing this course full time and have a lot of assignments on my plate. If I had the time to work it out, I might give it a go, but it wouldn't get me any extra marks in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a very high level: the data about each product is stored in a structured, computer-friendly format, not as HTML. Typically it will be stored in a database of some sort: SQL, NoSQL, whatever.

The product data is programmatically turned into HTML on-the-fly using some sort of HTML templating. It doesn't take much imagination to see how this part works. There's some "skeleton" structure (the template) into which the specific product information is substituted, using some sort of special placeholders.

Consider this totally-made-up template as an illustrative example:

```
<h1> {{ product_name }}  </h1>
<p> {{ product_description }} </p>
```

– can you see where this is going?

Comment: I figured as much. It must have been a mistake with the assignment specifications. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, it makes a lot of sense now actually. Thanks again.